# cocos2d remove tint

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

I'm trying to implement a highlight animation to my sprites. The sprite should highlight to a given color and gradually reverse back to its original colors, with the following code:

```
- (void)highlight {
    CCTintTo *tintAction = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:0.1 red:255 green:255 blue:255];
    CCTintTo *tintBackAction = [tintAction reverse];

    CCSequence *sequence = [CCSequence actions: tintAction, tintBackAction, nil];
    [self runAction:sequence];
}
```

Now this function raises an exception as CCTintTo doesn't seem to implement 'reverse', which makes sense. Is there any other way to implement removal of an added tint over an interval, using a CCAction?

Answer (score 3):

1. `CCSprite`'s default color is `ccWhite`, {255, 255, 255}, so if you
   want to make sprite lighter, you'll have to subclass `CCSprite`/write shader to use additive coloring.
2. Just tint it back:

   ```
   CCColor3B oldColor = sprite.color;
   CCTintTo *tintTo = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:t red:r green:g blue:b];
   CCTintTo *tintBack = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:t red:oldColor.r green:oldColor.g blue:oldColor.b];
   [sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions: tintTo, tintBack, nil]];
   ```

Comment: 1. "subclass CCSprite/write shader to use additive coloring" this sounds extremely interesting. I would appreciate more details on what you mean and how to do this in cocos2d, if you happen to have the time.
2. Already tried this. As you said, the default color for CCSprite is ccWHITE, and this piece of code just stores ccWHITE and basically repeats the 'tintAction' action in my code with no effect. Does not revert the sprite to its original state.

Comment: Google it. There are tutorials on both overriding draw method for additive coloring (for cocos2d 1.x) and writing shaders for cocos2d 2.x.

Comment: I'll be sure to google it. Thank you for your time and invaluable comments.

Comment: re: "no effect". well, you are doing something wrong. https://www.dropbox.com/s/awcs0x0efez0aqz/CocosTintTest.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can store previous color before start tint, then just create CCTintTo with initial RGB values.

Comment: Tried it to no avail. I'm not setting any color to the CCSprite before tintAction, and using this method does not remove the tint added by CCTintTo.

Answer (score 0):

For Cocos2dx (C++)

```
ccColor3B oldColor = sprite->getColor();
        CCTintTo* action = CCTintTo::create(0.5f, 127, 255, 127);
        CCTintTo* actionReverse = CCTintTo::create(0.5f, oldColor.r, oldColor.g, oldColor.b);;
        sprite->runAction(CCSequence::create(action, actionReverse, NULL));
```

Works fine Kreiri, thanks! I already gave a plus to you:).